# How to get keywords content after defined keyword

Tags: php

What is the best solution to get a *txt*s content after keyword *get*?

```
test (get; txt:"Sample text"; something_else;)

test (get; txt:"Sample text 1"; txt:"Sample text 2"; something_else;)
```

I've tried:

```
preg_match('/get; txt:"([^"]*)"/', $string, $output_array);
```

But it doesn't work for `txt: "</title>"` and it gets only first *txt*.

Comment: Where are you getting these strings from? They *almost* look like JSON.

Comment: Please define *best*

Comment: You've too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

A bit old-fashioned approach, but you can use `explode()` to get needed strings:

```
$str = 'test (get; txt:"Sample text 1"; txt:"Sample text 2"; txt:"</title>"; something_else;)';
$input = explode(';', $str);
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    $tmp = explode(':', $value);
    if (trim($tmp[0]) == 'txt') {
        $output[] = htmlspecialchars(str_replace('"', '', $tmp[1]));
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sample text 1
    [1] => Sample text 2
    [2] => </title>
)
```